# Is there a way to get only subscription for a user?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am wondering if there is a way to query for subscription with a filter based on creatorId ? When I use `$filter=creatorId eq guid string` 
I get a response of

> A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand
>   types edm.string and edm.guid for operator kind ‘equal’

I also tried guid’xx...’ or guid[‘xxx...’] both with no luck

Answer (score 0):

As the property is a string the query would be looking like this.

```
GET /v1.0/subscriptions?$filter=creatorid eq '844735a2-5360-4d79-b3d6-dd6aa4f567ee'
```

However, filtering is not supported on this property.

Comment: So there is no way to get subscription based on a creator ?

Comment: The only way today would be to get all the subscriptions and filter on the client side. If you'd like to request such a feature, please create an idea on https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com